# Problem installing wow with wine 1.7

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

I went to wine HQ to get the latest release of wine, i installed the battle net launcher and nothing crashed or froze. I started to install it and everything seemed to work fine, after i check the launcher after an hour it was at the same when i started it just saying "Installing...". Any suggestions why it's doing this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing more information. What have you tried to resolve this problem? What were the results? Did you receive any error messages?

Comment: Research indicates that there may be a bug in the installer. Source: http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/10311481250?page=2 Comments from source indicate that it should run under Wine. Have you tried the version of wine that is available in the software center? Try the Latest stable release: Wine 1.6.2

Comment: After posting this question the launcher just started to give me information that it is installing, before it was just saying "installing...", not sure why it took two hours to start which concerns me a little bit.

Comment: Many possibilities which have little or nothing to do with your installation. Examples: Overloaded server (or server farm), Network congestion, etc, etc,

Comment: Warning: Beta packages

The 1.7 packages here are beta packages. This means they will periodically suffer from regressions, and as a result an update may break functionality in Wine. If the stable 1.6 Wine version works for you, then you may not want to use these beta packages. Source: http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Comment: I was just thinking about it and i forgot i had a 30 gb game downloading which obviously could of been the reason for it taking a while. I did try 1.6 and the launcher crashed every time, i looked up the reason and wine added a fix to it in the 1.7 version, i like to stick with stable releases but sadly i can' do that. I really appreciate the help, great community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, Wine 1.7 has problems installing straight to the OS, you need to install PlayOnLinux from the software center, then do the following.
[image: Open PlayOnLinux]**Open PlayOnLinux**
[image: Click Install a Program from the menu to the right]**Click Install a Program from the menu to the right**
[image: Follow The Steps]**Follow the steps**
[image: Create the drive]**Create the drive**
[image: Chose the .exe file, follow the steps, restart PlayOnLinux, then run!]**Chose the .exe file, follow the steps, restart PlayOnLinux, then run!**
This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It started to give me an install time after two hours of waiting, i don't understand why it took that long to start to install. I will keep this as a reference for games i play on wine. Also, will Playonlinux improve performance for games?

Comment: No, not really, in fact it might make it a tiny bit slower, but PlayOnLinux will work for most all games. Even steam!

Answer (score 0):

"Why it's doing this?":

You forgot You "had a 30 gb game downloading". Depending on the speed of your connection and the load on the servers in question this is without a doubt the most likely reason.

Comment: Interesting enough, no. I did another test by installing it again and it did the same exact thing. Going to look and see if this is a common bug.

Comment: Did you miss "the load on the servers"? WOW is an insanely popular game.